# How make cross domain using tag manager and if I change my code site, what I lose?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

my website doesn't have the tag manager installed, but it has the analytics. I want migrate to tag manager e make cross domain with the checkout page. It's just use the same code generated by tag manager in all pages, or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the tag manager in all pages and configure the cross-domain in the analytics tags.

If you already have the cross-domain working, once you replicate it in the tag manager you don't lose any information.

For cross-domain implementation and troubleshooting see here:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/troubleshooting-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-analytics/

Comment: I need to put the code in each domain that I have, or the tag manager does this in cross domain? I have a checkout from a supplyer, its page needs my code from tag manager? Sorry, I'm very noob on this...

Comment: The sending of hits can be managed by GTM. Both domains must be configured correctly. I inserted a link in my answer where you can find how to configure GTM for cross-domain.

Comment: Great! If the post was useful mark the answer as correct, please.